# change .join('\n\r') based on val

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting up a jquery function to output an array to a `<textarea>`,

all values are then separated with `.join(\n\r)`, although I wish to have values use `.join(\n\r)` and values I have selected use `.join()` instead

I have attempted to use `.filter(x => typeof x === 'smeAssist')` in an attempt to have only 'smeAssist' use `.join()` although this seems to filter everything out, I assume I am using this incorrectly?

```
        $('#formOut').click(function() {  
        const ret = [
            {id: 'yesCheck', label: 'TL or SME Assistance'},
            {id: 'noCheck', label: 'TL or SME Assistance'},
            {id: 'smeAssist', label: ''}
        ].reduce((memo, {id, label, linebreak}) => {
            const val = $(`#${id}`).val();
            if (val) {
            if (linebreak && memo.length) {
                memo.push('-------------------------------------------------------')
            }
            if($(id == 'yesCheck' && '#yesCheck').is(':checked')) { 
                memo.push(`${label}: ${"Yes"}`); return memo;
            }
            if($(id == 'yesCheck' && '#yesCheck').is(':not(:checked)')) {
                return memo;
            }
            if($(id == 'noCheck' && '#noCheck').is(':checked')) { 
                memo.push(`${label}: ${"No"}`); return memo;
            }
            if($(id == 'noCheck' && '#noCheck').is(':not(:checked)')) {
                return memo;
            }
            if($(id == "smeAssist" && '#yesCheck').is(':checked')) {
                memo.push(`|${val}`); return memo;
            }
            if($(id == "smeAssist" && '#yesCheck').is(':not(:checked)')) {
                return memo;
            }
            else memo.push(`${label}: ${val}`);
            }
            return memo;
        }, []).join('\n\r');
```

Current result

```
TL or SME Assistance: Yes

|Test
```

I am trying to get the following result on any selected `id`

```
TL or SME Assistance: Yes | Test
```

Comment: `typeof x === 'smeAssist'` will always evaluate to `false`, `smeAssist` is not a data type in Javascript

Comment: your `id==` comparisions in `if()` shouldn't be inside `$()`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh, thank you I am still very new to javascript, is there a way I could use .filter for the intended result?

@charlietfl I tried removing them and it no longer functions? Is there a reason why they shouldn't be inside `$()` Thank you

Comment: @user10073459 wrapping them in $() identifies a jQuery Selector. jQuery will then try to find an element that matches the selector and your code is going to produce some weird results. That is why you should not use the `if()` that way.

Comment: @user10073459 unclear why you are using `.reduce()`.